# Receive realtime update from Instagram on post comment

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Updating media after instagram realtime update callback (https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/), and need to receive realtime update even on media comment, not only after creation.
It used to work (received realtime update on mine photo's comment), but its not working now, does someone have solution for that, is it still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram does not provide real-time updates for the creation of comments. You would need to create functionality that periodically checks media to see if new comments were added to it.